# spring cloud task taskLifecycleListener error when running in dataflow server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-task

I implemented the sample batch-job sample given in spring cloud task samples. The spring boot version used in that is 2.0.1.RELEASE. Since I have to port another job I have to spring cloud task I wanted to find the oldest version compatible. The jar for batch-job created with 1.3.2.RELEASE as the spring-boot version runs successfully. But when I run it from the UI of the spring cloud dataflow after adding it as an app I get the following error:

```
2018-09-18 11:51:02.755  WARN 12368 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found
2018-09-18 11:51:02.759  INFO 12368 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-09-18 11:51:02.763 ERROR 12368 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.listener.TaskLifecycleListener   : An event to end a task has been received for a task that has not yet started.
2018-09-18 11:51:02.767  INFO 12368 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
2018-09-18 11:51:02.781 ERROR 12368 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at io.spring.BatchJobApplication.main(BatchJobApplication.java:14) [batch-job-2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [batch-job-2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.doTaskStart(TaskLifecycleListener.java:233) ~[spring-cloud-task-core-2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.start(TaskLifecycleListener.java:355) ~[spring-cloud-task-core-2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mostly of Task not get registered in a given database. So When I got this Invalid TaskexecutionID issue, I passed database credentials to Dataflow server and same [DB details ] passed while launching a task. Generally both them should be in sink with DB credentials. finally all the TASK executions were recorded with TaskID, Execution Start time , Executio Endtime etc in that supplied DB.

> task launch taskTimestmp2 --arguments "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb  --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!